# java split string into array by a few charaters

Tags: java

got a string that looks like this:

```
"abc", "def", "ghi"
```

I need to split string to array like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

I tried:

```
String [] strArray = sb.toString().split(" ,\"");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" and *your example* doesn't make much sense... could you rephrase yourself please?

Comment: it doesnt split it. strArray.length() is equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

You firstly need to remove first and last quotation from string:

```
sb = sb.substring(1, sb.length() - 1); //remove first and last character
```

after above line of code your sb will be:

```
abc", "def", "ghi
```

and then try this regex:

```
String[] strArray = sb.split("\"\\s*,\\s*\"");
```

its split on the basis of `quote (any no of space) comma (any no of space) quote`

Answer (score 0):

the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method accept [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

consider the following code

```
str.split("(\", \")+|(\")+")
```

you will get a four elements array

```
[, abc, def, ghi]
```

As suggested by Zaheer you can remove the first "